# Automatic dynamic_cast for arguments in std::function

Tags: c++

We have polymorphic classes A and B like:

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() {}
};
struct B final : public A {
    void f() { std::cout << "f" << std::endl; }
};
```

I want to assign a variable with `std::function<void(A*)>` from the lambda function with the type of `void(B*)` without explicitly applying `dynamic_cast` for the arguments as

```
std::function<void(A*)> funcA = [](A* a) {
    [](B* b) { b->f(); }(dynamic_cast<B*>(a));
};
B b;
funcA(&b);
```

Are there any ways to automatically achieve this without wrapping the internal function with `[](A* a){}`?

Comment: Just to be clear, `{ b->f(); }` is a placeholder for a whole function body using `b`, right?

Comment: @Quentin Right.

Comment: This seems like a very contrived example. Can you perhaps elaborate on the actual problem you want to solve with this solution?

Comment: Shouldn't `f()` be virtual so you can just call it from the `A` instances?  No casting in that case.

Comment: I could solve this problem, but I do not want to.  Because you might use my solution.

Comment: A `dynamic_cast` conversion can fail, as you know. What do you expect to happen, in that case?

Comment: @Yakk this is becoming a running gag :D

Comment: @Quentin Hey, sometimes I instead solve problems in ways I would want nobody to use.  ;)  Search for `site:stackoverflow.com yakk named operator`.  It is an entire series of comedy.

Comment: @Yakk oooh yes I've seen that. Not sure what's my favorite between these ones and the inside-out mutant lambda you refused to write last time ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set off with the goal of making the following syntax work:

```
std::function<void(A*)> funcA = dynStdFunc([](B* b) { b->f(); });
```

To this end, `dynStdFunc` must:

1. Detect the parameters of the provided lambda;
2. <s>Detect the parameters of `funcA`;</s>
   *This isn't actually needed on our side, see the update at the end*.
3. Generate a new functor, which glues both parameter lists together via `dynamic_cast`.

---

**1.** Detecting parameters has alrady been the subject of [another answer of mine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/136050/46420). We can use the following type trait:

```
// C++17's void_t
template <class...>
using void_t = void;

// Pack of arbitrary types
template <class...>
struct pack { };

namespace detail_parameters {
    template <class F, class = void_t<>>
    struct parameters { };

    template <class F>
    struct parameters<F, void_t<decltype(&F::operator ())>>
    : parameters<decltype(&F::operator ())> { };

    template <class R, class... Params>
    struct parameters<R(Params...)> { using type = pack<Params...>; };

    // More specializations for functions, function pointers,
    // member function pointers...
}

// Retrieve the parameter list from a functionoid
template <class F>
using parameters = typename detail_parameters::parameters<std::remove_reference_t<F>>::type;
```

This takes in a functionoid type, and returns a `pack<T...>` containing its parameter types. Great.

---

**2.** the parameters required by the `std::function` aren't known from inside `dynStdFunc`. The way we make this work is by returning a temporary object, which contains a template for a conversion operator to `std::function<Ret(Args...)>`.

```
namespace detail_dynStdFunc {

    // F = functionoid, Ps = pack of its parameters
    template <class F, class Ps>
    struct wrapper;

    template <class F, class... Ps>
    struct wrapper<F, pack<Ps...>> {

        template <class Ret, class... Args>
        operator std::function<Ret(Args...)> () {
            // Now we know what parameters the `std::function` needs
        }

        F f;
    };
}

template <class F>
auto dynStdFunc(F &&f) {
    return detail_dynStdFunc::wrapper<
        std::remove_reference_t<F>,
        parameters<F>
    >{std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

---

**3.** We've got all we need, generating the new functor is straightforward:

```
template <class Ret, class... Args>
operator std::function<Ret(Args...)> () {
    return [f_ = std::move(f)](Args... args) -> Ret {
        return f_(dynamic_cast<Ps>(args)...);
    };
}
```

And that's it! You can [see it working live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4a0054b3c07cded).

---

**Update:** turns out I've done twice the work I needed to, because `std::function` can actually instantiate and wrap generic functors directly. Thanks Yakk!

So performing the conversion ourselves is pointless -- let's drop the `wrapper`:

```
template <class F, class... Ps>
auto dynStdFunc(F &&f, pack<Ps...>) {
    return [f_ = std::forward<F>(f)](auto *... args) -> decltype(auto) {
        return f_(dynamic_cast<Ps>(args)...);
    };
}

template <class F>
auto dynStdFunc(F &&f) {
    return dynStdFunc(std::forward<F>(f), parameters<F>{});
}
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/874c34d40b23db6a).

Comment: +1: Conditional use of something like `template<class T> struct auto_dyn_t { T* t; template<class U> operator U*()&& { return dynamic_cast<U*>(t); } };` would permit both dynamic cast pointers and non-cast arguments to be used.  Also permits outer wrapper to be `[](auto&&...)->decltype(auto)` instead of having match on the type of `std::function`.

Comment: @Yakk can a `std::function` call a generic functor?

Comment: @Yakk oooh. Now *that* was a Goldberg-grade overkill.