# Store variadic template arguments and pass them to lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates

I am trying to do something horrible with C++.

I have a function `f(void*, ...)` that needs to accept pointers to `int`, `double`, whatever. I have a lot of constructions like this:

```
void whatever() {
  somelogicHere();

  int a;
  double b;
  char c;

  f(&a, &b, &c);

  some(a);
  actions(b);
  onabc(c);
}
```

And I want to wrap that hanful of actions and variable definitions into some template, and call it like:

```
myTemplate([](int a, double b, char c) {      
      some(a);
      actions(b);
      onabc(c);
});
```

Small example of what must be done:

```
template<int S, typename ...A> 
void magicTemplate(const char(&fmt)[S], std::function<void(A...)> callback)
{
    char format[2 + S];
    format[0] = 'O';
    format[1 + S] = '\0';
    int s = S;
    memcpy(format + 1, fmt, S);

    // next lines is just a random stuff that does not work
    std::tuple<A...> local_arguments;

    extractArgs(format, &local_arguments...); //pointers to arguments must be passed
    callback(local_arguments...);  // arguments must be passed

}
```

... and call of my template:

```
magicTemplate("iii", [](int a, double b, char c)
{
    std::cout < a << std::endl;
    std::cout < b << std::endl;
    std::cout < c << std::endl;
});
```

First thing - my template does not match this argument, and the second thing - I have no idea what must be inside of `magicTemplate`'s body.

Comment: So, if I've got this correct, you want `myTemplate` to a) deduce the type of the argument list in the lambda (or std::function) passed to it; b) create variables of those types; c) pass the *address* of those variables to `f`; d) invoke the lamba?  Have I got that right?

Comment: I am having problems finding a question, let alone a clear question.  Can you create a [MCVE] showing a toy example of what is happening before, and a clearer idea of what you want to change the code to?

Comment: @Yakk: Me too.  I think the question is "how do I implement `myTemplate`?  It's not clear that this will save much repetition though - he still needs to write out the calls after the call to `f`, and the argument list to the lambda is just the same as the variable declarations.  All that's saved is the call to `f`.

Comment: @MartinBonner, exactly.

Comment: I want make `myTemplate` to do exactly the same as `whatever` function but for generic arguments of different count.

Comment: @crashtua But we don't know what `whatever` does, or what you mean by "the same".

Comment: @Yakk, I changed post and provided example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting some good mileage out of that [parameter-detection code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42439720/3233393) :)

Let's get this done first -- we want to get a list of parameter types from the type of whatever we passed to `magicTemplate`:

```
namespace glk {
    namespace tmp {
        template <class T>
        struct type_is {
            using type = T;
        };

        template <class...>
        using void_t = void;

        // Pack of arbitrary types
        template <class...>
        struct pack { };

        namespace detail_parameters {
            template <class F, class = void_t<>>
            struct parameters { };

            template <class F>
            struct parameters<F, void_t<decltype(&F::operator ())>>
            : parameters<decltype(&F::operator ())> { };

            template <class R, class... Params>
            struct parameters<R(Params...)> : type_is<pack<Params...>>{ };

            template <class R, class... Params>
            struct parameters<R(*)(Params...)> : type_is<pack<Params...>>{ };

            template <class T, class R, class... Params>
            struct parameters<R(T::*)(Params...)> : type_is<pack<Params...>>{ };

            template <class T, class R, class... Params>
            struct parameters<R(T::*)(Params...) const> : type_is<pack<Params...>>{ };
        }

        // Retrieve the parameter list from a functionoid
        template <class F>
        using parameters = typename detail_parameters::parameters<
            std::remove_reference_t<F>
        >::type;
    }
}
```

Now `glk::tmp::parameters<F>` gives us a `glk::tmp::pack<T...>` where each `T` corresponds to a parameter. Now, let's suppose we have that, and implement the actual body of `magicTemplate`:

```
template <std::size_t FmtSize, class AndThen, class... Args, std::size_t... ArgsIdx>
void magicTemplate(
    char const (&fmt)[FmtSize], AndThen &&andThen,
    glk::tmp::pack<Args...>,
    std::index_sequence<ArgsIdx...>
) {
    std::array<char, FmtSize + 1> fmtStr;
    fmtStr[0] = 'O';
    std::copy(fmt, fmt + FmtSize, fmtStr.data() + 1);

    std::tuple<Args...> args;
    std::scanf(fmtStr.data(), &std::get<ArgsIdx>(args)...);

    std::forward<AndThen>(andThen)(std::get<ArgsIdx>(args)...);
}
```

(I have replaced `extractArgs` with `std::scanf` for testing purposes, since they seem to be quite similar)

Now just a bit of plumbing to actually produce the required `std::index_sequence`:

```
template <std::size_t FmtSize, class AndThen, class... Args>
void magicTemplate(
    char const (&fmt)[FmtSize], AndThen &&andThen,
    glk::tmp::pack<Args...>
) {
    return magicTemplate(
        fmt, std::forward<AndThen>(andThen),
        glk::tmp::pack<Args...>{},
        std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{}
    );
}

template <std::size_t FmtSize, class AndThen>
void magicTemplate(char const (&fmt)[FmtSize], AndThen &&andThen) {
    return magicTemplate(
        fmt, std::forward<AndThen>(andThen),
        glk::tmp::parameters<AndThen>{}
    );
}
```

Et voilà! We can call this thing with the exact syntax you wished for. Of course, everything looking remotely like error checking has been left as an exercise for the reader :)

[Live demo on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a035d2fc0b011419)

Comment: what the... magic. Thanks, works exactly as I want. Going to learn something about c++ to figure out how this works :) Tested on latest VS 2017.

Answer (score 1):

You might use `std::apply` (c++17 but implementable in c++11)

```
template<int N, typename ... Ts>
void magicTemplate(const char(&fmt)[N], std::function<void(Ts...)> callback)
{
    char format[2 + N];
    format[0] = 'O';
    format[N + 1] = '\0';
    memcpy(format + 1, fmt, N);

    std::tuple<Ts...> local_arguments;
    std::apply([&](auto& ...args){ extractArgs(format, &args...); }, local_arguments);
    std::apply(callback, local_arguments);
}
```

Then, to transform your lambda into `std::function`, you might have something like:

```
template <typename C> struct helper : helper<decltype(&C::operator())> {};

template <typename Ret, typename C, typename ...Ts>
struct helper<Ret (C::*)(Ts...) const> {
    using type = Ret(Ts...);
};

template <typename Ret, typename C, typename ...Ts>
struct helper<Ret (C::*)(Ts...)> {
    using type = Ret(Ts...);
};

template <typename F>
std::function<typename helper<std::decay_t<F>>::type> as_std_function(F&& f) { return f; }
```

And so finally:

```
template<int N, typename F>
void magicTemplateFinal(const char(&fmt)[N], F&& f)
{
    magicTemplate(fmt, as_std_function(f));
}
```

Comment: hey @Jarod42, I've never seen such a construct before
`template <typename C> struct helper : helper<decltype(&C::operator())> {};`
Could you tell me how this trick is called and how it works

Comment: @Peregrin: Lambda (as `[](int i){}`) is a functor mostly similar to `struct L { void operator() (int) const {} }`. `operator()` *"is"* the name of the method, so the same way you might do `&C::method`, you might do `&C::operator()`. `decltype` allows to get its type, so something like `Ret (C::*)(Ts...) const`. Then it is simple inheritance, primary template works for classes: "`template <typename C> struct helper : helper<Ret (C::*)(Ts...) const> {};`", and specializations collect the wanted information.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation. I was mostly confused by the way inheritance works here. Now I see it's a great way of limiting possible template specializations.